# My CPU is working on 100% until I open Task manager

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, malware, cpu-usage

I am here because I have a problem. My CPU is working at 100% (while I am idle) until I open Task Manager. When I open Task Manager it shows that my CPU is on 100% and after a half seconds it  dramatically drops to 15% which is normal usage when I am doing nothing on my PC. Does anyone know what could be happening? Also, my Task Manager automatically closes after a few minutes of using it, so when it closes my CPU percentage comes back to 100%. I have no problem working on my PC while CPU is on 100% usage. It looks like this background process always leaves me enough resources so I can do whatever I want on my PC without noticing something is happening in background. I was trying to find an answer on the internet but I couldn't find it.

Hints I can give you:

1. Its not the problem with my CPU because I have tried my PC with another CPU and still happening.
2. I have read somewhere that my CPU is not actually on 100% of usage and it's just showing it like that for a few seconds when I run Task Manager until it loads the real CPU usage, but that's not true. I was monitoring my CPU load on a third party application and it constantly shows 100% CPU usage until I open Task Manager. Then it drops of course. I also noticed my CPU temperature is higher while my Task manager is not open, which proves what I said.
3. I think the process that takes all CPU usage percentages is called "System interrupts" or something like that. It's really hard to see this because this process immediately closes when I open Task Manager, but I could see it because it was there for like 1 second.
4. I have this problem for some time and I think that's even happening after I reinstalled my Windows. I am not 100% sure about that. As I said I cannot remember, but be aware that can be a possibility.

If someone can help me, I will be thankful.

P.S. dont tell me to reinstall my system, of course I will try that if I don't find other solution

Comment: Run DISM and then SFC.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: How have you determined your CPU is running at 100%. What software are you using to determine that?

Comment: Also set Task Manager to Hide (system tray) when minimized. Green Square minimized. Look at it . Dark Green suggests low CPU and Bright Green suggests high CPU. What is it doing?

Comment: Use a more advanced tool such as Process Explorer (from Sysinternals, owned by Microsoft) to get a better view into which sub processes are causing this high CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely been infected by bitcoin mining malware. They're often designed to shut down when you open up Task Manager so you don't notice them.

Download and run the Windows Process Explorer (it's the first link that comes up when you Google it) and see which file is using up all your power. Then open up Task Manger and you'll see it mysteriously shut down. That .exe will be the culprit, but they often have multiple .exe's that will install that file if you delete it.

For me it was a file called WinDefScan.exe and it was accompanied by Windefupd.exe, Wungfx.exe and Winsvc.exe. All were located in the same folder (Windows/System32). The best way to identify them is to find the .exe that's using all your power then figuring out which other .exes have a creation date similar to that one. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First, Windows has background tasks, such as [indexing files for Search](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/solved-microsoft-windows-search-indexer-high-cpu-usage-laura-leone).  defragmenting drives, completing a previous update, and [scanning for malware](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/defender-showing-high-cpu-usage/71c2c35a-1486-45ac-9a1f-d8b21d40ce53), which sometimes consume CPU time, and Windows can pause these tasks while you are using some application.

That said, malware may also behave the same way, i.e., "hiding" until tools such as *Task manager* are closed.

For that reason, I'd do the following:

- Perform a thorough scan for malware with at least two tools, such as Windows Defender while the HDD (or SSD) is mounted, and with an [offline malware detection app](https://askleo.com/offline-anti-malware-tools/). Start scans when you won't use the PC for a few hours.
- Check [what files are being indexed for Search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search-indexing-in-windows-10-faq-da061c83-af6b-095c-0f7a-4dfecda4d15a), and adjust to your needs.
- In drive *Properties*, on the *Tools* tab, check if disks need optimization, and perform that until the system stops doing so automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You must have installed a pirated game or something

1. Download Remote Process Explorer and monitor which process is taking cpu usage.
2. For me it was archiver some people have encounter different names like unarchiver
   It will be in C:\Users\Pc name\AppData\Roaming
   3.Check the created and modified date It must be on the same date when you installed your game and also check it's accessed time and lastly delete it
3. Disable ContentManagement in task scheduler.
   Hope this helps

Comment: That's quite a guess without much info.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133935)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue, and I don't have a solution yet, but in my case I can stop it from happening following three simple steps:

1. Open task manager
2. Find and end task for two instances of windows explorer running simultaneously
3. File > Run new task > explorer > Ok.

After this only one instance of Windows explorer keeps running.

This is only working until I reboot.